Listing stream-segment IDs for fluvial junctions with Field Calculator
Issue #3 as concerns my comeback geofictional project.
At this writing, I've tried my best (for many hours now) to come up with a Field Calculator formula that gives a list of comma-separated stream-segment IDs whose "NODE_B" values match a fluvial-junction ID, i.e. at a system's confluence. (For context, the layers are derived from the Channels [lines] and Junctions [points] output of SAGA's "Channel network and drainage basins".)
For instance, suppose a junction has 9 as the ID, corresponding to the "NODE_B" values of the channel strands with "SEGMENT_ID"s 9 and 17. My best shot at an FC formula thus far, overlay_intersects('Drainage Test', NODE_B) (from the Junctions layer), gives an array of three matches ([ 3, 9, 9 ]) as the result whereas it should be two. (The "3" refers to the strand with SEGMENT_ID 4, which is flowing downward from junction #9.)
How do I further refine the formula to reflect what I'm aiming for? (I've looked up GIS.SE for ideas and hints, but nothing's looked promising or substantial.)
(QGIS 3.30)

This is difficult to understand if you are not familiar with that tool. What layers do you have, a line and a point layer? Can you add a screenshot showing the data and their attribute tables

@Bera: The lines are the drainage segments, and the points the drainage junctions. Give me a bit of time before I GDrive the latter.

@Bera: Screenshots (for the junctions and the segments) now available on request via GDrive.
